# PHP, can't connect to the MySQL server

Tags: php, apache, ssh

What might be the reason of the following problem.

PHP function `mysql_connect()` works fine if I execute it from 
`command line (php -r "mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'db_user', 'db_pass');")`.

The same call with the same parameters fails for PHP running as an Apache module.

MySQL server is running remotely, connection to it is forwarded using SSH: ssh -fN -L 3306:localhost:3306 remote_host

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: `mysql_connect()` is depreciated, you should try to use `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: "fails" does not help here. What does that mean? Do you get an error? Well what is it? Do you get nothing? What do the log files say? Does the universe implode when you try to connect? Argh!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to be looking at using MySQLi or PDO as the older MySQL functions are deprecated.

This should help get you started:

```
<?php
//establish conection
$link = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","bd") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($link));

$query = "SELECT name FROM mytable" or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($link));

//execute query
$result = $link->query($query);

//display information
while($row = mysqli_fecth_array($result)) {
  echo $row["name"] . "<br>";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and details, I would say that the MySQL server is refusing to connect to your web server (where ever it is) because the connection is not secure (in one fashion or another). If you want to connect via the PHP module in Apache as easily as you do from the command line, set up your connection so that all encryption/ tunneling issues are resolved. That's what I would do.

However, make sure the following line is correct..

```
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'db_user', 'db_pass');"
```

Are you pointing to the correct server? I thought you said that the MySQL server was remote. This line suggests that you are attempting to connect to a local, imaginary MySQL server that is running on the same machine as the web server. Try getting the IP or domain name of the MySQL server and use that instead (in your web code, that is).